# Better alternative to many nested if statements in this context?

Tags: c#, if-statement, nested-if

```
if (task1 != null)
    //Do something with task1
else
{
     if (task2 != null)
         //Do something with task2
     else
     {
         if (task3 != null)
             //Do something with task3
         else
         {
             if (task4 != null)
                 //Do something with task4
         }
     }
}
```

Is there an alternative to the above code? I'm looking for a sort of 'flatter' way of kind of switch casing on the tasks depending which is not null.

Thanks a LOT in advance for anyone that can help.

Comment: @CodyGray is right in that salutations etc are discouraged, although more commonly done as part of a more substantial edit. But! You (SkonJeet) are being unnecessarily abrasive here - can we all play nicely? Thanks. Off-topic comments now removed.

Comment: Cody was in fact the first to confess to attempting to get a 'rise' out of me and I'm the one acting abrasively!? I simply answered the question he asked. Ridiculous at times this 'community'.

Comment: no, Cody was gently mocking your tone/accusation. Perhaps not overly constructive, but he wasn't "confessing" anything. It was sarcasm about the way you had spoken to him. In the same vein that if someone asked me "who are you, the fashion police?" I might (although almost certainly wouldn't) respond "yes, that's right, I'm the high-commissioner of the fashion police, and chairman of the clothing-league; that's why I take an interest". It wasn't helpful, (and indeed, was removed) but neither was it a confession.

Comment: Sarcasm is considerably more abrasive than someone simply answering a question. My tone was not at all confrontational and I don't recall making an accusation.

Comment: Sigh. First you went on about editing for upvotes, then you added "for such a ridiculous, petit discussion - I hope you don't do this in your spare time". This was not one-sided, but frankly this is pointless, and I've already cleared it down once, asking "all" to play nicely.

Comment: Would the fancy C# pattern matching of 7.0 help? https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/01/pattern-matching.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if your method does anything else. If it doesn't, you can use:

```
if (task1 != null)
{
    // Do something with task1
    return;
}
if (task2 != null)
{
    // Do something with task2
    return;
}
if (task3 != null)
{
    // Do something with task3
    return;
}
if (task4 != null)
{
    // Do something with task4
    return;
}
```

(I was about to add the same point that Marc was making - if you're going to do *the same thing* with whichever task is first non-null, then the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is indeed your friend.)

Comment: It does do something else after these if statements yes, my fault for leaving that detail out sorry - certainly an alternative I wouldn't have considered though, noted.

Comment: @SkonJeet: Could you extract this part its own method so that you *could* return from it? Basically we need more context...

Comment: I can extract it yes, which I think I will do. Thanks a lot Jon, appreciate it.

Comment: I remember learning that using return statements in this way is bad style and makes program flow harder to read. Is this acceptable in production quality code?

Comment: @Terribad: what was the context in which you learned that? There are some languages where it does lead to a mess if you're not careful... But in something like Java or C#, returning as soon as you know the result usually makes the program flow *easier* to read.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think it was in my C++ days. If doing this makes code easier to read then I'll use it more often! I always felt that it lead to cleaner code but I decided to adhere to the "rule".

Comment: @Terribad: Never obey a "rule" just because someone said to. You need to understand the reasons behind the rule, and the contexts in which it's valid. The pattern of "validate inputs, handle simple cases (returning early), handle complicated cases" often leads to much clearer code IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Point taken! But in a GUI application whose validation logic is based on certain combinations of multiple controls, sometimes deeply nested `if` and `if..else..else-if` statements are the only way. would you agree that returning inside the 3rd level of nesting is typically a bad idea? I would think it's better to declare the return value at the very top of the nested statements and then return it just before the function exits.

Comment: @Terribad: Nope, if you know that's the end of what you want to do in the method, barring `finally` statements, then a `return` statement expresses that more clearly than anything else, in my view.

Answer (score 13):

Are they all the same type? And do you want to do the same thing in each branch? If so, you could use null-coalescing:

```
var chosenTask = task1 ?? task2 ?? task3 ?? task4;
// do something with chosenTask
```

Comment: Superb!! Thanks Marc, supposing they are not the same type though and I simplified it for the sake of the question without in fact thinking it through (doh!), what now?

Comment: Couldn't I do the same - and then use 'as' to test the var in the if statement?

Comment: @SkonJeet if there is a common `interface` that they implement, you can still do the same thing (although you might need a cast somewhere). Otherwise, you might have to do it the ugly way.

Comment: This also relies on the OP wanting to do the same thing with whichever task is picked, not just the type being the same.

Comment: @SkonJeet if they all have a common API, then yes you can use `as` - however, if they are all very different, there is not much benefit doing that. It really depends on what "do something" is ;p

Comment: @Jon true, true (ok, I'm getting dizzy tracking JonSkeet and the oddly named SkonJeet in the same conversation)

Answer (score 3):

make all tasks implement an ITask with a Run() method, and add the tasks you want to run to an ICollection so you can iterate over them.

```
foreach (var task in TaskCollection) {
   task.Run();
}
```

Comment: My fault for providing false info (they are not all in fact tasks), upvote for your help anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use conditional operator, with condition that you need some variable on left hand side

```
var v = task1 != null ? do something : task2 == null ? do something : task3 != null ? do something : task4 != null ? do something : null;
```

Comment: Looks very messy on one line but I'm sure I can use this somewhere with proper formatting - thanks a lot Milan.